# Combine JSON objects contained in a single file into one JSON file using Pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark

I have a huge file of around 20 GB which contains JSON objects as shown below:

```
{"-LGsfNZANyy3sWBuNn5s":{"callsign":"6aay","deviceId":"97436FB5-B4DE-8D8E-0000-000000000000"}}
{"-LIIe7e7tz1BzSzhG1AK":{"callsign":"3fox","deviceId":"9A554634-2373-DFDF-0000-000000000000","dow":"Tuesday"}}
```

I need to create a single JSON object which contains all these objects inside it            as follows:

```
{"-LGsfNZANyy3sWBuNn5s":{"callsign":"6aay","deviceId":"97436FB5-B4DE-8D8E-0000-000000000000"},
"-LIIe7e7tz1BzSzhG1AK":{"callsign":"3fox","deviceId":"9A554634-2373-DFDF-0000-000000000000","dow":"Tuesday"}}
```

Can this be done using Pyspark? Any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just delete the closing } of every line except the last, and the opening { of every line except the first, and then append ,s on every line except the last? If your data is formatted exactly like that, it should work :P This obviously isn't good practice, but it's probably the easiest solution.

Comment: I have a nested JSON objects as well in a single JSON object which is why I'm looking for a concrete solution to merge each line of JSON object into a single JSON file.

Comment: That solution will work with nested JSON objects, as long as there is one full JSON object (in the format you showed) per line.

Comment: Ok. I'll try this suggestion. Thanks